# Box2D: Make bodies fall at random intervals

Tags: c++, opengl, timer, 2d, box2d

I am trying to develop a game in which I have several `b2PolygonShape` bodies and they should fall from the top. But what I want is I want them to fall from random positions and with some delay. What I have done so far does not get me this working i.e the bodies do fall but they fall together.I do not know hot to call the function with some delay! I cannot even call it from `display` function. And `init` function gets called only once. 
This is what I have tried so far:

`aadBrick` Functions which is actually for the body that should fall

```
b2Body* addBrick(int x,int y,int w,int h,bool dyn=true)
{
    b2BodyDef bodydef;  
    bodydef.position.Set(x*P2M,y*P2M);   //Setting body position
    if(dyn)
    {
            bodydef.type=b2_dynamicBody;  // dynamic body means body will move

    }

    brick=world->CreateBody(&bodydef);        //Creating box2D body

    b2PolygonShape shape;            //Creating shape object
    shape.SetAsBox(P2M*w,P2M*h);

    ////////////// Adding Fixtures(mass, density etc) //////////////


    brickFixture.shape=&shape;
    brickFixture.density=1.0;
    circleFixture.restitution = 0.7;
    brick->CreateFixture(&brickFixture);
    return brick;
}
```

This is `init` function

```
void init()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glOrtho(0,WIDTH,HEIGHT,0,-1,1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1);

    world=new b2World(b2Vec2(0.0,5.8));

    addGround(WIDTH/2,HEIGHT-80,WIDTH,10,false); 

    addBrick(80,0,10,10);// these bricks should fall with some delay not together
    addBrick(100,0,10,10);

    actor=addActor(80,460,50,70,false); // static body

}
```

And this is timer function, if it has something to do do with the delay!

```
void Timer(int t)
{
world->Step(1.0/30.0,8,3);

glutPostRedisplay();
glutTimerFunc(1000/30,Timer,1);
}
```

Comment: You are doing two addBrick at the same time. You just need to wait before doing the second one.

Comment: How to set that "wait" thing?? Thats what I am asking

Comment: How can I achieve some kind of delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest next solution:

```
    int mCounter = 0;

    #define MAX_DELAY 60

    void Timer(int t)
    {
        if (mCounter <= 0)
        {
            // rand() % 100 - random value in range 0 - 99
            addBrick(rand() % 100, 0,10,10);

            mCounter = rand() % MAX_DELAY;
        }
        mCounter -= t;

        world->Step(1.0/30.0,8,3);

        glutPostRedisplay();
        glutTimerFunc(1000/30,Timer,1);
    }
```